# How to read specific lines into R?

Tags: r

I want to read a set of specific lines specified by indices from a txt file into R, for example

```
index = c(2, 5, 9, 99, 100)
```

meaning the 2nd, fifth, etc lines into R. How should I approach this? Shall I use

```
scan (file, skip = index[i]-1, nlines = 1)
```

with a for loop?

Comment: And keep rbinding the results of the `scan()` - should work.

Comment: BTW. this might be very slow if you're reading a lot of lines one by one. If so, then I suggest you pre-allocate a dataset with the same number of rows you intend to read and then keep updating each row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lapply`:

```
lns <- lapply(index, function(i) <your scan line>) 

do.call(rbind, lns)

# or
data.table::rbindlist(lns)
```

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` does not work in my case (R version 4.1), returning always the same line (number one).

The proposed loop works. Here is a working example.

```
lines<-c(3,5,900,1000)
items<-c()
for(i in 1:length(lines)){
    item<-scan(file,skip=lines[i]-1,nlines=1)
    items<-c(items,item)
}
```